# YII2, rest API without database connection

Tags: api, yii2

I have been studying how to develop a rest API with YII and everything is clear from the documentation.

In the documentation they suggest using ActiveRecord however I will have inside my application some controllers that do nothing in the database, I mean they work with vectors or files or for example complex controllers that have to update several tables in the database or make queries to other APIs to later make updates.

What do you think is the best approach to fix this?

I would like to keep the same "Bearer Token" authentication for all controllers regardless of whether it is a simple one that works with ActiveRecord or a complex one that involves other actions.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: The suggestion from the Yii docs of using ActiveRecord it's because they are assuming that you are going to create the CRUD endpoints for an entity (model). You can not using and continue to be able to use its [HttpBearerAuth](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-auth-httpbearerauth) filter. You just have to return what you need (tipically a json structure) instead of rendering a view in the controller.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand what you are saying. but i am trying to do it and i get errors. Maybe you have an example or sniped? or any URL where you can read more about how to do it this way

Answer (score 0):

```
Public function actionExample(){
// do stuff
// $result
return json_encode($result);
}
```